# Calculator | How to sum two button.text in the same text box

Tags: c#

please help, I'm so stuck, I want to create a calculator program in c#, and I want to make the method of sum & multiplication, division... from another class called Calculator, so I can call it to the button equal when I click it, so I tried this, and nothing work, so I need a method button click event! 
the code :

```cs
namespace MY_Calculator_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             Button btn = (Button)sender;

             TB_DashBoard.Text = TB_DashBoard.Text + btn.Text;

         }

         private void somme(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Calculator calc = new Calculator();
             calc.sum();   
         }

    }

    class Calculator
    {
        public double a { get; set; }
        public double b { get; set; }
        public double result {get;set;}

        public double sum()
        {
            result = a + b;
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Button click is not doing anything with the calculator. Can you show us your complete code?

Comment: is not that long, i just add an event to a button number on calculator, so when I press it its shows us the text on the textbox [TB_dashboard.text]

Comment: You dont seem to use the `private double sum()` at all. Also, why do you have the `Result` of the calculator in the constructor? Shouldnt be the calculator the thing that calculates the sum/difference/etc.? You cant just sum up two `*.Text` attributes because those are strings. Parse the value of the string to a double/int/etc. and use that to calculate the results.

Comment: In this state we cant really understand what happens. Share the code so that it is understandable or provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok i understand what you saying  , oki feel stupid now , let start over , I want  a method sum
and shows up the result in the text box , and value from button number like a simple calculator program

Comment: Dont feel stupid, just try to understand yourself what you are doing and try to articulate it in a good manner. Second: May you share the code where you initialize your `Calculator`- class? Otherwise connections might not be as clear as it looks like.

Comment: ok i update my post to my whole code, is that set?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you trying to do.
It seems that in the button click event you are checking if the Text box value equals to "." and if so you append to it another dot so it will contain "..".
If it does not equal you append the text value of the button pressed.

The calculatore class is not used in any place.
In order to use it you need to create anew instance like:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculatore();
calc.sum()
somthing = calc.result;
```

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to mention that I already declared in Form1.cs (Calculator cal = new Calculator();)
and the checking if the Text box value equals to "."   is just something Im trying , all i want to do is call the method from other class and make show us the result to the textbox

Comment: So what is the problem you are having?

Comment: can u show me how to convert the btn.text to value so I can use it in the method of sum ?

Comment: You mean convert string to a double?
you can use double.Parse() or double.TryParse()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're code is trying to do, but you're missing few key actions. Check out this code, it could definitely be cleaned up much better but should give you an idea.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string op = ""; // last operator
        private float output = 0;
        private bool nextOperand = false; // this flag tells you if you're entering the second operand

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void operand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (nextOperand)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = "";
                nextOperand = false;
                if (op == "=")
                {
                    lblOperations.Text = "";
                }
            }
            txtOutput.Text += " " + ((Button)sender).Text;
        }

        private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // I've set the tag to the text of the operator
            var nextOp = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
            if (nextOperand)
            {
                // if the user clicks an operators right after each other, reset the operator
                ResetOperator(nextOp);
            }
            else
            {
                // if the user clicks an operator, calculate the previous operation
                Calc(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // reset your calculator
            lblOperations.Text = "";
            txtOutput.Text = "";
            output = 0;
            op = "";
            nextOperand = false;
        }

        private void Calc(string nextOp)
        {
            var operand = float.Parse(txtOutput.Text);
            if (output == 0)
            {
                output = operand;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (op)
                {
                    case "+":
                        output += operand;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        output -= operand;
                        break;
                    case "x":
                        output *= operand;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        output /= operand;
                        break;
                }
                txtOutput.Text = output.ToString();
            }
            lblOperations.Text += operand.ToString() + " " + nextOp;
            op = nextOp;
            nextOperand = true;
        }

        private void ResetOperator(string nextOp)
        {
            lblOperations.Text = lblOperations.Text.Remove(lblOperations.Text.Length - 1, 1);
            lblOperations.Text += nextOp;
            op = nextOp;
        }
    }
```